# Python: Overload compare method of property variable

Tags: python, properties, compare, getter-setter, class-method

I want to overload a class method(s) (`__eq__`, `__lt__`, ...) of a property value. Has anybody an idea?

Here is my propery value for `version`:

```py
class Element():
    def __init__(self):
        self._version = None

    @property
    def version(self):
        return self._version

    @version.setter
    def version(self, value):
        ''' setter for version '''
        self._version = value
```

## Question

It is possible to overload a class method e.g. `__eq__` for this property variable?

I want to call an own `__eq__` function in case of compare the property variable:

```py
elem = Element()
elem.version = '1.1.1'
print(elem.version == '1.1.1') # here I want to call my own __eq__ function
```

## First Ideas

I tried some stuff like this but I could not find a solution:

```py
class Version(str):
    def __init__(self, value:str=None):
        self.value = value
        
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.value)
        
    def get(self):
        return self.value

    def set(self, value:str=None):
        self.value = value
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('this should be called when I compare the property value')
        return str(self) == str(other)

class Element():
    def __init__(self):
        self._version = Version()

    @property
    def version(self):
        return self._version.get()

    @version.setter
    def version(self, value):
        ''' setter for version '''
        self._version.set(value)
        
elem = Element()
elem.version = '1.1.1'
print("> first test: elem.version == '1.1.1' ")
print(elem.version == '1.1.1')
print("> second test: elem.version.value == '1.1.1'")
print(elem._version.value == '1.1.1')
print("> third test: elem.version == '1.1.1'")
print(elem._version == '1.1.1')`

The output looks like this:
`> first test: elem.version == '1.1.1' 
True
> second test: elem.version.value == '1.1.1'
True
> third test: elem.version == '1.1.1'
this should be called when I compare the property value
True
```

My `__eq__` function is called only in case of the third compare test (compare of the class Version()). I want to call an own `__eq__` function in case of compare the property value.

Comment: The fact that it's in a property is basically irrelevant. If you want to override the behaviour of `==` on `elem.version` then you need `elem.version` to return an instance of a class where you overrode `__eq__`. You have it returning a string.

Comment: It isn't a "property value". It is a `str` object. Suppose, you have `<an expression> == <another expression>`, then the only way to control how `==` will work is by controlling `__eq__` on the *type* of whatever <an expression> or <another expresssion> evaluate to. Here it is `str`. Generally, you can't (without heroic effort) patch built-in methods, and even then, monkey-patching is not a good choice if you can avoid it

Answer (score 0):

It might be helpful to use `from typing import overload` which can be implemented like this:

```py
from typing import overload

class MyClass:
    @overload
    def my_method(self, arg1: int) -> int:
        pass

    @overload
    def my_method(self, arg1: str) -> str:
        pass

    def my_method(self, arg1):
        if isinstance(arg1, int):
            return arg1 + 1
        elif isinstance(arg1, str):
            return arg1.upper()

obj = MyClass()
print(obj.my_method(1)) # prints 2
print(obj.my_method('hello')) # prints 'HELLO'
```

Which gives this result:

```
2
HELLO
```

Caveat:  i am not a fan of overloading and try to avoid it (primarily because i often see comments stating that "*method overloading is not supported natively*").

Answer (score 0):

[@khelwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood) you're absolute right. Thanks a lot!

Here is my **solution**!

```py
class Version(str):
    def __init__(self, value:str=None):
        self.value = value
        
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.value)

    def set(self, value:str=None):
        self.value = value
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('this should be called when I compare the property value')
        return str(self) == str(other)

class Element():
    def __init__(self):
        self._version = Version()

    @property
    def version(self):
        return self._version

    @version.setter
    def version(self, value):
        ''' setter for version '''
        self._version.set(value)
        
elem = Element()
elem.version = '1.1.1'
print(elem.version)
print("> first test: elem.version == '1.1.1' ")
print(elem.version == '1.1.1')
```

The **output** looks like:

```py
1.1.1
> first test: elem.version == '1.1.1'
this should be called when I compare the property value
True
```